# Bootstrap order elements not working for xl devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Thanks in advance for any help and direction. I'm trying to reorder my form elements for xl size.

For devices up to xl:
1 , 2, 3, 4

For devices xl and upwards:
1, 2, 4, 3

The elements are different col widths but I don't think this should affect the order.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <form id="form-story row" class="form form-style_block">
                <input type="text" class="form-element col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 order-xl-first"
                    placeholder="What's your name?"/>
                <input type="email" class="form-element col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 order-xl-2"
                    placeholder="What's your email?"/>
                <div class="form-group form-element form-element_textarea col-12 order-xl-last">
                    <p class="text-placeholder">Here is a place for your story:</p>
                    <textarea class="textarea" rows="10"
                        placeholder="Please write a description of your story. Maximum 5000 characters. Media files allowed: .jpg, ,png, .pdf, .mp4"></textarea>
                    <p class="text-sub"> By clicking ‘send’ you agree to our Privacy Policy and allow us to share your
                        data.</p>
                </div>
                <input class="button-tertiary no-padding form-element col-12 col-xl-4 order-xl-3"
                    type="submit"></button>
            </form>
```

In xl devices the submit button should move before the text area button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For devices up to xl it means you have to declare a breakpoint before `xl`, which is `lg`

```
            <form id="form-story row" class="form form-style_block">
                <input type="text" class="form-element col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 order-lg-1 order-xl-1"
                    placeholder="What's your name?"/>
                <input type="email" class="form-element col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 order-lg-2 order-xl-2"
                    placeholder="What's your email?"/>
                <div class="form-group form-element form-element_textarea col-12 order-lg-3 order-xl-4">
                    <p class="text-placeholder">Here is a place for your story:</p>
                    <textarea class="textarea" rows="10"
                        placeholder="Please write a description of your story. Maximum 5000 characters. Media files allowed: .jpg, ,png, .pdf, .mp4"></textarea>
                    <p class="text-sub"> By clicking ‘send’ you agree to our Privacy Policy and allow us to share your
                        data.</p>
                </div>
                <input class="button-tertiary no-padding form-element col-12 order-lg-4 col-xl-4 order-xl-3"
                    type="submit"></button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Hey :) this didn't work for me the order isn't affecting the containers

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, I had row as the ID of the parent container as opposed to adding the class row.

```
        <form id="form-story" class="form form-style_block row">
            <input type="text" class="form-element col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 order-1 order-xl-1"
                placeholder="What's your name?" />
            <input type="email" class="form-element col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 order-2 order-xl-2"
                placeholder="What's your email?" />
            <div class="form-group form-element form-element_textarea col-12 order-3 order-xl-4">
                <p class="text-placeholder">Here is a place for your story:</p>
                <textarea class="textarea" rows="10"
                    placeholder="Please write a description of your story. Maximum 5000 characters. Media files allowed: .jpg, ,png, .pdf, .mp4"></textarea>
                <p class="text-sub"> By clicking ‘send’ you agree to our Privacy Policy and allow us to share your
                    data.</p>
            </div>
            <input class="button-tertiary no-padding form-element col-12 col-xl-4 order-4 order-xl-3"
                type="submit"></button>
        </form>
```